# Combining two streams into one

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following code:

```
// ...
String currentName = ...
String newName = ...; // possibly same as currentName.
                      // in such a case, no exception should be thrown

AnimalEntity animal = animalKeeper.getAnimals()
    .stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getName().equals(currentName))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoResourceException("No animal with that name"));


if (animalKeeper.getAnimals()
    .stream()
    .filter(a -> !a.getName().equals(currentName))
    .anyMatch(a -> a.getName().equals(newName))) {
  throw new BadRequestException("You already have animal with that name");
}

// ...
```

The code works fine, but I am not happy that I needed to iterate twice over the streams.

Can I somehow achieve the same result in one-go?

Comment: Given that you want to throw two different exceptions on error, are you sure you want to combine the two streams?

Comment: I believe that `currentName` was actually found and filtered out in second stream. `anyMatch` is operating upon a subset of `animalKeeper` that *does not* contain `currentName` hence *You already have animal with that name* statement is misleading.

Comment: The first stream does not process all elements. It stops at the first match. The second can be skipped completely when `currentName.equals(newName)`, which would be easy to check beforehand. So fusing both operations into one would result in an operation that has to perform far more work.

Comment: @Holger Could you take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64547678/13886040 Some users on SO does not want to help because they don't know the answer and instead marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai The message could be improved, but what do you find incorrect with the code shared in the question?

Comment: @Naman Yes I am talking about the code in the question as I mentioned in my question as well.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai There is nothing wrong in the code, except for a minor redundant variable for `currentName`.

Comment: @Naman I feel 'You already have animal with that name' is not logically correct. Please review my question.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai It is correct, any animal in the existing list which has a name different from `currentName` and same as `newName` throws a BadRequest. Why do you feel it is not logically correct?

Comment: @Naman That condition will never arise since first stream expression will throw an exception and abort if currentName aka newName will only set when code does not throw an exception.

Comment: @Naman You changed the question itself with your edit.

Comment: @Holger The question was changed, it is no longer the same. Please go through the original question if you have time.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai Re-read the code with and without the edit. It's logically the same still. Try and understand what the question actually is about. (Introspect!) Think of cases when `currentName` and `newName` could be the same and also when they could differ and how would one handle all possible cases as per OPs expectation.

Comment: @Naman It is no longer the same. In original question, currentName was being set after first stream evaluates which was dependent on results of first stream aggregate. Now you made it arbitrary which totally changed its meaning.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai With the previous code, the value of `currentName` could always have been equal to that of `someName`(which was arbitrary) or otherwise there was always the exception being thrown. So effectively, `someName` and `currentName` were always the same value, which holds true with the updated code as well. That's when I said, there was a redundant variable in the code shared.

Comment: @Naman Yeah I missed that. Coming back to my original question 'You already have animal with that name' is logically incorrect since that condition can never arise due to exception thrown in first stream.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai Okay. Consider this input of animal names `["Cat","Dog","Rat"]` and further few test cases with sample data TestCase1: `currentName="Dog";newName="Lion"`, then TestCase2: `currentName="Cat";newName="Rat"` and then TestCase3: `currentName="Dog";newName="Dog"`. Which one do you think would have inappropriate output? (If none, share a sample input of yours.)

Comment: @Naman According to your test cases on input "Cat" and "Rat", the code throws "You already have animal with that name" which is *logically incorrect*. Do you understand what my question was now?

Comment: @Naman Why it is logically incorrect? Because "Cat" and "Rat" are not equal.

Comment: Looking at the number of comments I understood how misleading it really was. LMAO. Sometimes it takes time to realize what some user is pointing out so don't worry @ConcurrentBhai

Comment: @AniketSahrawat So true :) I think I have made my point now.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai You did that in the first place itself. As I already pointed out, don't worry about opinions because they are not the facts. People always try to understand things from their perspective (which is not wrong) but they ignore details. You picked it up. Good for you.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai Do you care to explain, why is it logically incorrect to throw a Bad Request exception for a name that already exists and is also an input to the API exposed? Cat is existing and so is Rat, but if the `newName` exists one might want to throw a BadRequest. What is incorrect about it? Are you mixing up two different exceptions and treating them as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code condenses to:

- a no-op check (new name being old name)
- that **all** animals do not contain this new name
- that you can find the animal by its old name

So:

```
if (!newName.equals(oldName)) {
    if (animalKeeper.getAnimals().stream()
            .anyMatch(a -> a.getName().equals(newName))) {
        throw new BadRequestException("You already have animal with that name");
    }
    Animal animal = animalKeeper.getAnimals().stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getName().equals(oldName))
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(throw new NoResourceException("No animal with that name"));
    animal.rename("Koniara");
}
```

A crucial improvement would be be able *to find animals by name*.

```
if (!newName.equals(oldName)) {
    if (animalKeeper.mapByName.containsKey(newName)) {
        throw new BadRequestException("You already have animal with that name");
    }
    Animal animal = animalKeeper.mapByName.get(oldName);
    if (animal == null) {
        throw new NoResourceException("No animal with that name"));
    }
    animal.rename("Koniara"); // remove+put
}
```

A HashMap would make that fast.

You could in one stream collect at most 2 animals, with old or new name. But it does not change anything in time complexity: N steps with one branching. Also you can only stop looping when the collected result size is 2. That certainly does not look better. 2 Separate queries can be faster.

Comment: `findAny` does not take parameters. So it has to be `filter(predicate).findAny()`, as in the OP’s code. A Map approach is usefil, but the objects contained in a map should not have a reference to the map, so it should not be the responsibility of `Animal`’s `rename`  method to update the map. You can replace the `get` invocation with `remove` and have done half the job already. And when you check for `containsKey(newName)`, you should also use `newName` in the `rename` call.

Comment: @Holger findAny corrected. I did not want to write `getMap().get(...)` and `getByName` which would be fine, does not show any mappiness.

Comment: I did nowhere suggest to write `getMap()`. First, you do a `containsKey(newName)` check, then you do `animal.rename("Koniara")`. That’s just inconsistent. Further, the entire line `animal.rename("Koniara"); // remove+put` suggests that this method is responsible for updating the map that is actually in `animalKeeper`. But the `animal` should not do the `animalKeeper`’s job. Oh, and you got the syntax for `orElseThrow` wrong. It should be `.orElseThrow(() -> new NoResourceException("No animal with that name"));` The argument is a supplier for the exception, not a `throw` statement.

Comment: @Holger I will better myself; took too little time